# When i try to build wheel for dlib it says that i need cmake in order to do so. But i already have Cmake installed

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

When i try and install dlib using pip (pip install dlib) it says this:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\curry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qhiyfkci\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\curry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qhiyfkci\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ckv17yp4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qhiyfkci\dlib\
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext

    ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\curry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qhiyfkci\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\curry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qhiyfkci\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ckv17yp4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\curry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried to do pip install cmake and then pip install dlib but it did not work
Also for clarification i have installed Visual Studio community and use python 1.9. I use Windows 10
Thank you for Helping

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f

Comment: I still have the same error when i complete the last step. CMake downloads Just fine though

Comment: Do you use python 1.9? I suppose it should be 3.9

Comment: Also, have you added Cmake and Visual Studio to path

Comment: I do use python 3.9 but how do you add Cmake and Visual Studio to path (sorry for the amateur question I've just started using python)

Comment: It is given in the link above.